# Construct a dynamic query (or algorithm) based on existing query

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm

I have a task to construct a dynamic query (or algorithm) based on existing query with user choosed fields. Let me explain:

Lets say I have a function

ConstructQuery(string inputQuery, string[] mandatoryTables, string[] userFields) with 2 input parameters:

- inputQuery: string query with many fields and tables, joins and where conditions
- mandatoryTables: a list of mandatory tables
- userFields: a list of fields that user choose in some web or desktop app

Function would have to return optimized query with tables and joins that are only needed for query to succeed.

inputQuery is for example constructed like this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.SomeFieldA,
    Table2.SomeFieldB,
    Table2.SomeFieldC,
    Table3.SomeFieldD
FROM   Table1
JOIN   Table2 ON Table1.Code = Table2.Code
JOIN   Table3 ON Table2.Code = Table3.Code
WHERE  Table1.SomeConditionField = "xyz"
```

userFields are: SomeFieldB, SomeFieldC

mandatoryTables: Table1

So the expected query is:

```
SELECT
    Table2.SomeFieldB,
    Table2.SomeFieldC
FROM   Table1
JOIN   Table2 ON Table1.Code = Table2.Code
WHERE  Table1.SomeConditionField = "xyz"
```

My question is: is there a tool of some sort for solving this kind of problems or how you guys would solve it? I'm thinking of binary trees…

Regards,
Jani

Answer (score 1):

This is something called join removal. This is (very) hard. Just parsing the query is nontrivial, then You'd have to analyze semantics, consider what are the unique keys, what are foreeign keys to have a chance to remove some tables. In Your example: the algorithm would have to know that table3.code is unique, and a foreign key to table2.code, otherwise the queries are not equivalent.

It could be easier to generate the right query in the first place. This is what some ORMs do.